# How to loop over multiple filtered regex strings

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter, each

I do not know how to better track down the question. What I want to do is to look for every e-mail-address matching my `regEx` in different `div.test`, to create `<a href="mailto:">` links.

This does work, but if there are multiple mail addresses inside one div, only the first one gets highlighted. Whats the problem?

```
var regEx = /(\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*)/;

$(".test").filter(function() {
    return $(this).html().match(regEx);
}).each(function() {
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace(regEx, "<a href=\"mailto:$1\">$1</a>"));
});
```

[**JSBIN**](http://jsbin.com/sazegipufi/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: add a `g` on the end of your regex..

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp Like @Keith said use the global flag

Answer (score 2):

You must add the **global** (`g`) flag to you regexp:

```
var regEx = /(\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*)/g
```

Otherwise your regex will halt after the first match.